# jquery append with large amount of html

Tags: jquery, append

I have been using $.get to get the contents of my lightbox

```
$.get('sidebar-lightbox.html', function(data, elem) {

//DO STUFF HERE
 });
```

I am looking for  neat way to add large(ish), maybe 20 lines, of HTML into append. At the moment am doing

```
 $('.selector').append('<div id="wrapper"><div id="inner"><div id="content"></div></div></div>')
```

this is a bit messy and unreadable as the html gets bigger, looking for a nice way :).

Comment: Do you need to do it dynamically? Can you load it hidden and then just change the state?

Comment: yes needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('<div/>', { id: 'wrapper' }).appendTo('.selector');
$('<div/>', { id: 'inner' }).appendTo('#wrapper');
$('<div/>', { id: 'content' }).appendTo('#inner');
```

If you prefer, you could also have done something like:

```
$('<div/>', { id: 'wrapper' }).append(
    $('<div/>', { id: 'inner' }).append(
        $('<div/>', { id: 'content' })
     )
).appendTo('.selector')​;
```

You can of cours set any number of attributes here, remember to put the ones that are JavaScript keywords in strings, i.e. `$('<div/>', { id: 'id', 'class': 'x' })`. You could also chain multiple `.attr` and `.html` calls to get the markup you want.

Comment: this is kind of what I was looking for how are the multiple appends for performance? S

Comment: @welovedesign: there is always a performance overhead when using jQuery instead of JavaScript. Unless you're calling the method an extreme number of times, I wouldn't worry too much about it. When testing on my machine, creating and appending in that manner executes in ~20k operations/second, compared to ~40k ops/s for appending strings. However, you need to put that in the perspective that pure JS performs ~430k ops/s, so that's a cost you're always paying for using frameworks at all. [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-perf)

Comment: For clarity in your keyword string, "class" has to be in quotes because it's an actual jQuery term, correct?

Comment: @Jon: `class` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript. You can't create a variable named class. Some browsers will allow you to create an object property named class, without using the string notation to create it, but IE will not allow it. jQuery has built in support for mapping `class` to `className` and `backgroundColor` to `background-color` (the latter when setting styles, not attributes, of course), but jQuery wouldn't in itself mandate that they are strings. They are strings because it's the only way to construct the JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

Create a var first then append it. It will be more readable

```
var stuff = '<div id="wrapper">';
    stuff += '<div id="inner">';

// etc. then you append it
$('.selector').append(stuff);
```